# OSX nginx php-fpm 7 setup

Tags: php, macos, nginx

I have nginx running as confirmed by loading an html page.
The difficulty is running a .php page in same location, however this giving a 404.
fpm is shown to be installed okay using `php-fpm -t`
Therefore I am very sure its in .conf or a serverblock.
My goal is to set everything using serverblocks (aka VirtualHosts) as so much easier to manage differing projects so have attempted to strip nginx.conf to a minimal:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and the serverblock

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                root /var/www;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri /index.php?&query_string;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

index.php fails simply with a message 'File not found' though not in the usual nginx format - just those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assumed this would be simple on a Linux based OS. It seems Apple have messed with it too much to make it viable.

I have expertise in this and have a Ubuntu based script which makes everything ready to go on this Linux flavour - apparently Apple no longer support developers.

Oh well lets see how long it takes to install a VirtualBox solution that I can edit on OSX.

This is an answer per se pending details from other people answering as I have had this working before - I just wanted a non proxy solution and was prepared to find a few days finding it. Alas Apple prevent it.

Comment: Virtualbox is the answer otherwise you are trying to get a non standard Linux based OS (OSX) which has been messed about to perform better than a pure Linux flavour. I think OSX is not an appropriate server host, though got IDEs to communicate with the VBox Ubuntu Server via Samba

Comment: MacOS have never been Linux based. It's kernel, Darwin, derives from NeXTSTEP, which is essentially Mach/BSD.
Also, consider actually posting your answer, if you mark it as correct.